# How to unzip a file inside a zipped folder without unzipping the folder.zip using command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, zip

I have a zipped folder : folder.zip, the zip contains file1 and file2. I want to unzip file1 without unzipping folder.zip (Like what we can do using WinRaR). I want to be able to do this scenario using command line :

- open (Without unzipping) folder.zip and display content
- Find file1 inside folder.zip
- Unzip file1
- Get at the end file1 unzipped and folder.zip

I tried to do it using WinRaR application, and I'm expecting to do it using command line.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `unzip folder.zip my/file/in/folder/file1 the/other/file/in/folder/file2`?

Comment: What this command do exactly ? Why there is file1 and file2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried `unzip zipfile.zip '*/file1.txt'` and it works. Thank you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).